# Comparing date and time

Tags: vb.net

I want to write an alarm clock application that should display a certain message at a time set by the user.
How to compare system date and time with the time set by users in a text box?
Thanks
Furqan

Answer (score 2):

You can convert `TextBox.Text` value to a `DateTime` value as the following:

```
String dateTimeFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt";    
DateTime dateTimeValue = 
    DateTime.ParseExact(textBox.Text, dateTimeFormat , 
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

---

[DateTime.ParseExact Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ee1y0t7.aspx) converts the specified string representation of a date and time to its DateTime equivalent. The format of the string representation must match a specified format exactly or an exception is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the intellisense feature ... but the hint is:

`DateTime.Parse` ....

and you need a timer, I called him "timEr" (you should name him better ....), and read the answer from [Akram](https://stackoverflow.com/users/657974/akram-shahda), he made it culture independent ....

```
Private Sub timEr_Tick(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) _
    Handles timEr.Tick

    timEr.Enabled = False
    If DateTime.Now >= DateTime.Parse("29.06.2011 17:29") Then
        MessageBox.Show("Time to leave the office ....")
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! This works except for bringing the timEr.Enabled=False at end, after End If

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to use `System.DateTime` object

Just make sure when you take a users input from a text box, that you save it in a `DateTime` object, then you can use the generic `DateTime.Equals` to compare the two.

```
Dim currentDateTime As New System.DateTime
Dim alarmDateTime As DateTime
currentDateTime = Date.Now
alarmDateTime = 
    New DateTime(2011, Month(Date.Now), dayInput, hourInput, minuteInput, 0)
If currentDateTime.Equals(alarmDateTime) Then
  'alarm code
End If
```

Something to this effect shold get the job done.

**EDIT**: The parse method outlined in one of the other solutions would be better for creating your alarmDateTime object than manually doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using *VB.NET* you can use the functionality in `Microsoft.VisualBasic.DateAndTime`. For example, you could use `DateTime.Parse` (or better, `.TryParse`) to get a `DateTime` representation of the user's value, then check whether the system time is within, say, one minute of the user's time. This way, you don't need to mess with seconds.

```
Dim diffInMinutes As Long = 
    Microsoft.VisualBasic.DateAndTime.
        DateDiff(DateInterval.Minute, userTime, DateTime.Now)
```